How to list all files changed in commits pointing to specific directory?
$ git log --stat -- /root/llvm-project/lldb/source/Plugins outputs something like this:
...
commit fca51911d4668b3a6b79eb956327eb81fad3f40c
Author: Bill Wendling <5993918+bwendling@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 11 00:33:40 2024 +0000

    [NFC][Clang] Improve const correctness for IdentifierInfo (#79365)
    
    The IdentifierInfo isn't typically modified. Use 'const' wherever
    possible.

 lldb/source/Plugins/ExpressionParser/Clang/ASTUtils.h                             |  2 +-
 lldb/source/Plugins/ExpressionParser/Clang/ClangASTSource.cpp                     |  7 ++++---
 lldb/source/Plugins/LanguageRuntime/ObjC/AppleObjCRuntime/AppleObjCDeclVendor.cpp |  4 ++--
 lldb/source/Plugins/TypeSystem/Clang/TypeSystemClang.cpp                          | 11 ++++++-----
 4 files changed, 13 insertions(+), 11 deletions(-)
...

But I'd like to see all files changed in commits, not only from the specified dir (lldb/source/Plugins):
$ git show --stat fca51911d4668b3a6b79eb956327eb81fad3f40c
commit fca51911d4668b3a6b79eb956327eb81fad3f40c
Author: Bill Wendling <5993918+bwendling@users.noreply.github.com>
Date:   Thu Apr 11 00:33:40 2024 +0000

    [NFC][Clang] Improve const correctness for IdentifierInfo (#79365)
    
    The IdentifierInfo isn't typically modified. Use 'const' wherever
    possible.

 clang/include/clang/AST/ASTContext.h                                 |   4 +-
 clang/include/clang/AST/Decl.h                                       |  37 +++++-----
 clang/include/clang/AST/DeclObjC.h                                   |  89 ++++++++++++------------
...

Could you recommend the right command, please?

The magic option is --full-diff:
git log --stat --full-diff -- /root/llvm-project/lldb/source/Plugins

